# Scaling Imagemaps in HTML

Tags: html, imagemap

I have an existing HTML page which contains an image with corresponding image map.

I want to use the image in a different page, but need to scale it as the available space is smaller. The problem is that if I scale the image then the image map no longer works with it.

How can I achieve the same effect as an image and image map combination, but allow the image to be scaled?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an image map resizer:

http://blog.outsharked.com/p/image-map-resizer.html

Simplified version of the essential code it uses looks like this:

```
map.find('area').each(function() {
    var j,coordx,coordy,
        area = $(this),
        coords = area.attr('coords').split(','),
        isVisible=true,
        newCoords = ''; 

     for (j = 0; j < coords.length; j+=2) {
             coordx = parseInt(coords[j],10);
             coordy = parseInt( coords[j+1],10);

             // ignore last coord if uneven numbers (meaning it's a circle)

             newCoords += (!newCoords ? '' : ',') + Math.round(coordx * xAmount) + 
                (j+1<coords.length ? ','+ Math.round(coordy * yAmount) : '');
        }
}
```

It basically iterates through each area, recalculating the coordinate data.

You should be able to coordinate this with a `window.resize` event to change the size of your imagemap and image simultaneously.  Because window.resize fires many times as a user scales the window, you probably don't want to try to resize the imagemap every single time the event fires. Since it's computationally intensive, it could cause a slow user experience. Instead, buffer it and only do a resize every once in a while.

Here is a fiddle showing how to buffer window.resize events to do the same thing using the ImageMapster jquery plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/jQG48/